# MySQL is not allowing ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for a DATETIME field

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have seen a lot of related questions, but I cannot place my finger on this specific question:

I have a MySQL table with both a TIMESTAMP (for when the field was created) and a DATETIME (for each time the field gets updated).  It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE 'vis' (
ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
ENTRY VARCHAR(255),
AUTHOR VARCHAR(255),
CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UPDATED_AT DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(255)
)
```

When I try this though, the error I am getting is: `(SQL Error: 1294 SQL State: HY000) - Invalid ON UPDATE clause for 'updated_at' field`

Everywhere I have read (even on Stack Overflow) suggests I should be able to do this, yet I am getting this error.  Perhaps there is another way to have a field that automatically updates the time each time I update it?

I am using MySQL Server 5.5.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`DATETIME` cannot use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on update. Instead, change it to a `TIMESTAMP`.

Or, consider using a trigger for this situation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

EDIT: As in the comments (thanks @АлександрФишер!), this is no longer the case since MySQL 5.6.5, so another solution is to upgrade your server if possible.

Comment: This totally worked, thank you!  I got rid of `ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP` on the table declaration, and then I processed this syntax after creating the table: `CREATE TRIGGER 'vis_update_entry' BEFORE UPDATE ON 'vis' FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
And now it updates every time that I update that particular row.

Moral of the story: **Anywhere online that says you can do two TIMESTAMPS or a DATETIME with ON UPDATE is FALSE!**  At least for MySQL Server 5.5.

Comment: @MichaelPlautz - always good to see a "thanks, I solved it with your resource" rather than "ok but I need code for doing this on a trigger", thanks :)

Comment: The used version seems to be very important. Documentation says it shall work if MySQL Version 5.6 is used: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html. I cannot confirm because my server runs with 5.1 :(

Comment: For new visitors: As stated by @АлександрФишер , it depends on what MySQL version you are using.

Since 5.6 version, you can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on both DATETIME and TIMESTAMP

Comment: instead of just `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` you should always put  `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to make it more accurate instead of blank timestamp

Answer (score 5):

That feature appears to have been introduced in 5.6.  Works as expected on my default OS X install.

Reference: [Automatic Timestamp Properties Before MySQL 5.6.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html#idm139923373307456)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL ***does not*** allow functions to be used for default `DateTime` values. (See MySQL Data Type [Defaults](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html).)

Answer (score 1):

**INSERT and UPDATE date/time automatically**

*Works with data type: DATETIME or TIMESTAMP*

*Tested on: MySQL 5.6.27-2 and MariaDB 10.1.10*

---

Stores the current date and time on **INSERT**

```
CREATE TABLE table_demo (
    ...
    `CreatedAt` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ...
);
```

Stores the current date and time on **INSERT** and **UPDATE**

```
CREATE TABLE table_demo (
    ...
    `UpdatedAt` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ... 
);
```

Stores the current date and time only on **UPDATE**

NOTE: when INSERT, the default value is '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

```
CREATE TABLE table_demo (
    ...
    `UpdatedAt` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ...
);
```

Comment: This not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, and if you change it to timestamp , with neither `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` nor `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, it is the same as specifying both `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Please clarify: without any modifiers, it automatically defaults and updates?

Answer (score 0):

The TIMESTAMP and (as of MySQL 5.6.5) DATETIME data types offer automatic initialization and updating to the current date and time. For more information, see [Section 11.3.5, “Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look my picture.

Set column Filed Type **timestamp**, Attributes **on Update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** & Extra also . No problem after changed the filed type in Database, in my case . But not sure for all case. [image]