# How to set default current datetime in Mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, default-value

I am working on one project having frontend as `PHP` and backend `MySql` with XAMPP server.

I have one field named "created" with datatype as `DATETIME` in `MySQl`.I required to pass defauld current datetime value to this field.

I knew that there are some function in `PHP` to add current datetime to `MySql` database like

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

In some case(possible by mistake),PHP code may not pass datetime in mysql and defaul it is taking "0000-00-00 00:00:00" by `MySql`.

Can any one guide me to what word I need to add as default value for this created field.

I have tried to add CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value.

But It give me error :

```
 #1067 - Invalid default value for 'created'
```

Can anyone give me direction on this.

Thanks.

Comment: first echo $date on this page and also check created field type from table change it varchare  type

Answer (score 1):

Setting `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value is only possible if you have `MySQL` version `5.6.5` or later. Otherwise you can only set a default value of `0` to a `datetime` type column.

Example @ [***MySQL Fiddle 5.5.32***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3450)

You can try the following example on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and will learn that it is not supported using `MySQL 5.5.32`. Change it to `5.6.6` and following example should be working.

Example @ [***MySQL Fiddle 5.6.6***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ec7c)

**Example from my local server**:

```
mysql> create table ts( dt datetime default current_timestamp );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.54 sec)

mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.6.15    |
+-----------+
```

**Refer to MySQL documentation**:

- [***Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, you should make the field a `TIMESTAMP` and not a `DATETIME`.

Or, consider using a trigger for this situation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

(as slugonamission said in this thread: [MySQL is not allowing ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for a DATETIME field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882663/mysql-is-not-allowing-on-update-current-timestamp-for-a-datetime-field))

Answer (score 0):

Please Change `TYPE` from DATETIME to `timestamp` and in DEFAULT select `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Hope this will work.

Note : You do not need to give length/values

If you want to update your record on any update,change attributes to `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0):

Although Mysql solutions have been provided by other users here but if you want to use PHP then make sure all other values of your created column are set to their default values. A simple query like below is sufficient to enter correct values in DATETIME field using PHP. Remove the default value for the created column and make sure you'r query systax is proper.

```
mysql_query("insert into table (created) values('".$date."')");
```